# How to set vertical scroll to modal popup on body

Tags: css

I am trying to get scroll to modal popup. After i opened modal popup If pressed f12 for inspect element i want to get vertical scroll to my modal popup.If i move vertical scroll popup only move..How do it in css?
http://jsfiddle.net/sdjf48be/2/

css:

```
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100%; /* Full width */
height: 100%; /* Full height */
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
background-color: #fefefe;
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border: 1px solid #888;
width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: `.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}`         Try this instead of your .model class

Comment: Not working... Do not edit width and height

Answer (score 0):

**Don't scroll parent component when Modal is opened** its same as in your condition you want also **to set vertical scroll to modal popup on the body**.

So there is a callback called onAfterOpen. you can install a callback to disable the desired element.

OR in CSS, something like:

```
.ReactModal__Body--open {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Which will prevent overflow-y on the body whilst the modal is open.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

change the `overflow` from `auto` to `scroll`

```
overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
overflow: scroll; /* Enable scroll if needed */
```